# java.sql.ResultSet: flawed by design?

Tags: java, jdbc

This is the signature of `java.sql.ResultSet.next()`:

```
public boolean next() throws SQLException
```

As you all know, the method returns true if more rows are available into the `ResultSet`.
But what if a `SQLException` is thrown? There's no way for me to obtain `next()`'s return value, so there's no way for me to know if more records are available (there's no trace of a `hasNext` method into the interface).

Let's switch perspective. I'm working on a JDBC driver that needs to be fault tolerant (it reads from csv). How can I let my users know if more rows are available after a wrong row?

Comment: what do you mean by 'wrong row' here?

Comment: I'd consider using the JDBC API to parse CSV files to be more flawed than the fact that `ResultSet#next()` throws a `SQLException`. Use a real CSV parser (there are lot of 3rd party ones) or use a real DB (there exist embedded DBs like JavaDB, H2, etc).

Comment: This is just avoiding the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in that API design.
`next()` - Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. So a JDBC driver has just a  cursor for the result set. It gets every row from the database via that cursor every time you call next() method. It is only logical to hit some "Exceptions" in scenarios dealing with very large number of rows as part of querying a table.

Since you are "designing" your own csv based driver, **you are free to alter the `next()` API's behavior**. Though the signature states that it might throw `SQLException`, you may code the `next` method's implementation such that it returns an empty or partially filled object in order to make it fault tolerant.

There are obsolete techniques to find total number of records in a ResultSet - such as
calling `last()` and then calling `ResultSet::getRow()` to find out count of records before you begin to iterate.

Comment: I'm against signaling errors through return values. The problem is: one functions is trying to do two things at once: fetch the next row, and tell the user if there's yet another row after it.
It is much more useful to have an hasNext() function to do the second task. Looks like isAfterLast is what I was looking for. I didn't see it into the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you to decide whether your implementation actually throws an exception from these methods, just because it's on the interface doesn't oblige you to throw it. But if something goes wrong where your driver has trouble figuring out whether there is a next row, I doubt it is going to be recoverable. I mean, if your underlying code throws an IOException for whatever reason (network access, permission, hardware glitch, some other process deleted the file out from under you), throwing an exception may be the reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Maybe there's just a row in the csv with a column less. This is a recoverable situation.

Comment: @agdev: that does sound recoverable, so don't throw the exception for that case. it's your driver, how you comply with the api is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isLast()` to determine whether you are on the last row. However, this will also thrown an `SQLException`.

Comment: Great! You gave me the right idea. I can use isAfterLast() (instead of isLast()) to check if I'm beyond my ResultSet limit BEFORE calling next(). This makes next()'s return value unneeded.
The javadoc warns against the use of isLast(), because of possible performance issues. However, it says nothing about isAfterLast(). I assume it to be efficient. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

while most agree that JDBC is polluted with (checked!) exceptions everywhere, the meaning of the exception is "Sorry, I don't know, this error occurred", that's why it does not return a value when an exception is raised. Such a case is "i lost connection", or something even worse happened.

If you know there is a row after that one, return true.

If that next row is a malformed one, throw an exception when the malformed row is fetched, even if you would be able to detect it during execution of the "next()" method.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLException` should here only be thrown if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set. (see ResulSet's Javadoc)

In both cases you do not want to go on using the result set. You may want try to close it if the exception occurs and afterwards throw it away.

I cannot see a problem here: Either you've a next row or not. And when problems occur then throw the Exception.

If you want something that recovers from Exceptions here then build something **around** it rather than trying to "break" the common behaviour of these interfaces.

But maybe you should think about to not implement a JDBC driver for reading CSV-Data first.

Comment: These are the project's specs. I can do nothing about it :(.